# getting error "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" Linq to SQL Database Insret a XML file As VarBinary

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

i am getting error

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

```
public static void SaveDashboardStream(string connectionString, MemoryStream ms)
{
  using (DashboardDBConDataContext db = new DashboardDBConDataContext(connectionString))
   {
     DBDashboard storedDashboard = (from t in db.Dashboards
                                               select t).FirstOrDefault();
     ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     storedDashboard.DashboardStream = new Binary(ms.ToArray());
     db.SubmitChanges();
  }
}
```

i am using above code in a function As

```
private void DashBoardGenerator_DashboardSaving(object sender, DashboardSavingEventArgs e)
{
  // Determines whether the user has called the Save command.
  if (e.Command == DashboardSaveCommand.Save) 
  {
     try
     {
       using (MemoryStream saveStream = new MemoryStream())
       {
         Dashboard.SaveToXml(saveStream);
         DashboardSql.SaveDashboardStream(dashboardStorageConnectionString, saveStream);
       }
       e.Handled = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
      XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unable to Save Dashboard", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
  } 
}
```

PLease guide if i am wrong anywhere ?

Comment: In which line you are getting this exception? You can check it from stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `storedDashboard` seems to be null.

```
using (DashboardDBConDataContext db = new DashboardDBConDataContext(connectionString))
{
     DBDashboard storedDashboard = (from t in db.Dashboards
                                    select t).FirstOrDefault();

     //Always check for null when selecting First() or FirstOrDefault()
     if(storedDashboard == null) {
        storedDashboard = new DBDashboard();
     }

     ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     storedDashboard.DashboardStream = new Binary(ms.ToArray());
     db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but why stream is not getting data as i am storing it from xml to stream.

Comment: I don't think that `saveStream` has anything in it once you do this `using (MemoryStream saveStream = new MemoryStream())`, you should assign some value to it.

Comment: I found the problem is basically here             "                MyDashboard storedDashboard = (from t in db.Dashboards
                                               select t).FirstOrDefault();" can you tell me what is the correct syntax as i have 3 fields in DB "ID(Identity),Name,File"

Comment: Do you have a where condition to look for a specific dashboard? if you need a certain field value then `(from t in db.Dashboards select t.Name).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: My Database table is empty has nothing in it and i am using this function just to save my provided dashboard xml file to array and then to database.

Comment: So do you want to create a new dashboard with stream? Do you have a property `DashboardStream ` in `DBDashboard` model?

Comment: [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DashboardStream", DbType="VarBinary(MAX) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
  public System.Data.Linq.Binary DashboardStream
  {
   get
   {
    return this._DashboardStream;
   }
   set
   {
    if ((this._DashboardStream != value))
    {
     this.OnDashboardStreamChanging(value);
     this.SendPropertyChanging();
     this._DashboardStream = value;
     this.SendPropertyChanged("DashboardStream");
     this.OnDashboardStreamChanged();
    }
   }
  }

Comment: First() will throw an exception if the result list is null, the null check should only be done if you are using FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Thank you every one issue has been fixed with adding  db.storedDashboard.InsertOnSubmit(storedDashboard);